# ¿Puede asignarse un Coste fijo en lista de materiales no dependiente de unidades en orden de produccion?

Tags: odoo, odoo16

En Odoo necesito crear una lista de materiales con el coste de un producto fijo.

La idea es que al crear una orden de producción y asignar la lista de materiales, mientras que el resto de productos varían dependiendo de la cantidad, uno de ellos quede fijo independientemente de la cantidad indicada en la orden de producción.

Por ejemplo el coste de la puesta en marcha de la maquinaria es el mismo tanto si se fabrica 1 solo producto como si se fabrican 1000. ¿Cual sería la mejor manera de conseguirlo?